# Custom mysql sort by field value

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a question about mysql sorting. I have a database field with data like this `1,6,3,8,4`. I exploded this field value and made custom query for another table: `WHERE id='1' or id='6' or id='3'...`.

It works fine BUT the result is `ASC by id`. Is there a way to make the result appear at same order as the query?

Comment: Don't use `ORDER BY` clause!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY FIElD(id, '1', '6', '3', ...);
```

See it in action here:

- **[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41e06f/1)**

Comment: What if you have a `GROUP BY` before? For example, the first value i want, appears at the end?